# Getting an HTTP response status code of 0 and empty message using C++ curl library libCPR

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, https, openssl

I'm using [libcpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr) to send a GET request.

```
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(
            cpr::Url{target.str()},
            cpr::Header{header});
```

For debugging, I print the response—

```
    std::cout << "Response Error: " << r.error.message << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response Error Code: " << (int)r.error.code << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response Status Code: " << r.status_code << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response Text: " << std::endl;
```

—and get the following:

```
Response Error: 
Response Error Code: 4
Response Status Code: 0
Response Text:
```

I see a lot of seemingly relevant threads online, but I feel like I've tried everything and I don't know what my particular issue is. I think someone more versed in curl, CMake, or OpenSSL might be able to spot it. So here's what I tried / know:

1. **I don't think it's a problem with my code per se**—more likely a problem with my setup (dependencies, options, etc.) Because the code works for a different target, *i.e.* I can hit "https://api.binance.us/api" and get a 200 and response I expect. It's for the targets "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com" and "https://api.kucoin.com/api" that give me a 0 and empty response.
2. **I am able to get real responses using Postman.** When I std::cout the request headers to send the same exact request using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), I do get a response:

   [image]

   (Don't worry, I've modified the values.)
3. For Windows users there was [a thread](https://issueantenna.com/repo/libcpr/cpr/issues/704) earlier this year about an issue with HTTPS requests, stemming from an issue with vcpkg. I am on macOS Big Sur (11.6.5) so this is not my issue.
4. Just 1 month ago there was [a thread](https://bytemeta.vip/repo/whoshuu/cpr/issues/709?page=2) that seems relevant. 17 days ago they appear to have "fixed" this issue ([PR #733](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/pull/733))—so I have pointed CMake to the latest version of libcpr, 1.8.3:

   ```
   include(FetchContent)
   FetchContent_Declare(
           cpr GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libcpr/cpr.git
           GIT_TAG db351ffbbadc6c4e9239daaa26e9aefa9f0ec82d) # 1.8.3
   FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpr)
   target_link_libraries(myProgram PRIVATE cpr::cpr)
   ```

   Still no go for me.
5. Here's what CMake outputs in case there's a hint in there I don't see:

   ```
   -- Enabled curl SSL
   -- curl version=[7.80.0]
   -- Could NOT find LibSSH2 (missing: LIBSSH2_LIBRARY LIBSSH2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
   -- CA path only supported by OpenSSL, GnuTLS or mbed TLS. Set CURL_CA_PATH=none or enable one of those TLS backends.
   -- Enabled features: SSL IPv6 unixsockets libz AsynchDNS Largefile alt-svc HSTS
   -- Enabled protocols: HTTP HTTPS
   -- Enabled SSL backends: Secure Transport
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   ```

   Multiple threads say that versions before `7.81.0` work fine.
6. I also tried adding the option `cpr::VerifySsl{false}`, but get back

   ```
   SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
   ```

   I kind of don't think that's the right path anyway.

Does anyone have ideas? Any other output or thing to try that might be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it's the simplest thing that I didn't try. This warning tipped me off:

> -- Could NOT find LibSSH2 (missing: LIBSSH2_LIBRARY LIBSSH2_INCLUDE_DIR)

I simply did a `brew install libssl2` and it now works.